# Transformation Hierarchy - applying a parent's orientation to its children

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, transformation, quaternions

**My goal:**

- When being rendered, a child object needs to render relative to its parent; thus its own position and orientation need to be relative to its parent

**My problem:**

- Translations work, but the parent's rotation/orientation isn't correctly being added to a child's transformation calculation; the child rotates on its own orientation fine, but when the parent's orientation is added the calculated vertex for the child is rotated **twice as much**

**My approach:**

- When calculating gl_Position in my vertex shader, I pass the shader my mvpMatrix, object vertex, object position, object orientation, parent position, and parent orientation.
- Within the shader I've defined structs for holding a quaternion, as well as methods for rotating a vector by a quaternion, **which work on their own** when I rotate an object by itself.

  ```
  gl_Position = mvpMatrix * (vec4(parentPosition,1) + rotVertexByQuaternion(parentOrientation, vec4(objectPosition,1) + rotVertexByQuaternion(objectOrientation,vertex) ) );
  ```

Here's a picture depicting what I aim, and what I get. I omit adding the parents position in this example, because it is 0,0,0, but it would be done last anyways.
I've labeled 1 vertex green for the child object and traced it all throughout, so that the rotations can be traced. Also, the current step in my calculation is displayed beneath each panel.
[image: Example of the issue]

Comment: Why would you send positions and rotations as explicit parameters to the vertex shader when you're already sending the MVP-matrix?

Comment: My guess is that you already apply the parent rotation to the child rotation, don't reapply then in the shader

Comment: @Dolda2000 my mvpMatrix is really just the view and projection matrix. I had no idea how to approach hierarchical transformations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't you find it would be a better idea to include the model transformation in the matrix also? :) Either way, if you don't post the actual code, it's going to be fairly hard to debug.

Comment: @dolda2000 I have no idea how to set one up. All this time its just been a default blank matrix.

Comment: Using the MVP matrix is indeed the standard way of applying translations and rotations to models. There are tons of tutorials on the web. Even old OpenGL-1.0 tutorials often apply in this case. Doing it that way also allows you arbitrary levels of nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I still had some leftover old code applying manual orientation changes to all children of a parent, outside of the shader, as suggested by @ratchet freak
I thought it was just a coincidence resulting from bad math, but it turned out to actually be a full **double** rotation of the parent orientation.

So, the problem was fixed by removing those lines of code so that the code I've posted in the opening post actually works.

Further, apparently my implementation is less than ideal, instead I should learn how to create a proper model matrix, but for now the problem is technically closed.